# Is there an "undo" button in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, undo-redo, qgis-2.18

In ArcGIS there an option of "undo" button

[image]

I seek this option in order to return my steps if it necessary.

I try to find such option in the menu and didn't found any like it.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl + Z`? For me, it is the very first option in the `Edit` menubar.

Comment: i don't mean in the edit session , but general "undo" like in ArcGIS

Comment: Could you explain ArcGIS undo's behaviour for those who are not familiar with it?
Since 2.16 (I think), there is also an undo button for styles and labels (with history) in the layer styling panel.

Comment: I saw in Qgis 2.18 and it´s looks like there´s no that "UNDO" with the same properties as that on ArcGIS.

Comment: You have an undo-redo menu option, but it is not functional in all the situations. When you are using node tool for example, it works, but if you delete a shapefile or change (and save) the changes, it doesn't work. You must be very careful.

Comment: In the print composer, you can undo changes using the Command History window.

Comment: In the Toolbar of the "edit" - "Undo"